# Must force MS SQL Server (2012) to return to it's "virgin" state when re-running an edited T-SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Very often extremely trival edits cause my T-SQL scripts to fail when *rerun* from within a MS SQL Server 2012 edit window (e.g. "SqlQuery1.txt").  Frustratingly, there's no pattern to what (edits) cause this problem.  Coping with this has forced me to jump through some wierd hoops.

An example:  I changed exactly 1 character in a working query (from  "Set @THisColumn = 1" to  "Set @ThisColumn = 1"; the "H" was changed to "h'" to match the variable declaration).  When the script was rerun MS SQL Server 2012 gave me this error:

```
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 54
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

My research shows this message gets thrown when there is a problem with a TABLE which should be impossible in the above case.  The error is unimportant, *my problem is much more general* - having to use the following unsatisfactory "workaround":*

Copy the (edited) script into a new edit pane ("SQLQuery2.txt").  It works - until the next time it's edited.  Which then forces me to use another edit pane ("SQLQuery3.txt").  Repeat ad nausum.

Having to do this supports the theory that the problem is somehow related to how the edit pane works - NOT the script. (Hence the title of this question)

Using this "workaround" destroys my train of thought while the resulting large number of open "scratchpad" windows causes me to lose track of what I was doing ("... lets see now, is it version 13, 17, 26 or 28 that is the last "known good" version?...).

My suspicion is that SQL considers every *subsequent* rerun as being a part (a continuation) of the FIRST invocation of that script.   So it tries to be "helpful" (*not!*) by "optimizing" the query.
In a development environment this "assistance"  is very premature - and exactly what I do NOT want to have happen. (First make it work...*then* optimize it.)   How do I supress this undesirable behavoir?

From my research I know that my scripts must have lines like this one before creating a temporary table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID( 'tempdb..#XYZ)  IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #XYZ
```

and for a temporary procedure:

```
IF OBJECT_ID( 'tempdb..#ABCD) IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE #ABCD  
GO  -- Required before defining any procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE #ABCD
```

The need to do this implies that my supposition may be correct (why else would you need to do it?).

What else has to be done so that every time I press the "execute" button I get a "clean restart" of SQL?

Other factors to keep in mind:

- The script, invoked from Python 3.x, is periodically (and
  frequently) run as batch/cron job (i.e. an automatically scheduled
  task).  This means that any form of manual intervention (e.g. using
  tools like  MS 2012 Management Studio etc.) is not an option.
- Stored procedures aren't allowed, instead the python application reads a file of SQL commands that get passed to SQL for execution 
  (in effect emulating a user who types in those commands at a SQL
  console).
- Finally the script must also work for users that have the minimum
  possible  (e.g "guest") privileges

.

Comment: I can't imagine how, for example, changing the case on a SQL variable would cause that specific error, even if it did cause an error (which it shouldn't).

Comment: I recommend 3 things if you are not already using, 1.use source control (like GIT) to manage your code,(Free) 2. Get Sourcetree program, to visually see the changes (Free) 3. For the query part this link might help [DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-dropcleanbuffers-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I've already tried some DBCC commands. Unfortunately we (and the script) will never have the necessary privieges to use them.

Comment: My hypothesis is that the editor is changing more than it appears.  You might get some insight by examining the binary content of the TXT files. Has it changed from ASCII format to Unicode? Were spaces changed to non-breaking-spaces?

Comment: I could imagine that changing the case of one letter could cause a query to fail if the server's default collation was case sensitive.  But not with that particular error message.

Comment: sounds like you are creating temp table on the fly in the script. And for some condition, the no of columns in the temp table changes. Try pre-create the temp table at the beginning of the script using `create table #temp` and not 'select * into #temp'

Comment: You've essentially got what's going on in my script.  I'm doing what you suggest before I use dynamic SQL - which uses PIVOT and ALTER TABLE (to add/remove columns to #temp) - to produce the final "CSV-with-header-line" result set. However the problem predates use of those objects and occurs with simple queries so it's not likely specific to my query.  Instead it's how to "restart" the sql session in a clean state (as if I closed & reopened the file - but without ever having to do so).  Any Ideas on how to do this?

Comment: It is not a case of "there is no pattern to what edits cause this". It appears to be a case of "I don't know enough about this to recognise the pattern". I suggest you make some more effort to understand why the errors are occurring. It's not because the editor is doing something weird. It's because databases save data and state and if you run the same query twice the state is different therefore different things happen. If you were to take the time to explain your very first problem in more detail, it would require to analyse your inputs and outputs and you might just understand the issue